# Convert JSON to XML

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, xml-serialization

I know this has been asked many many times.

But honestly with so many tries, the solutions are not working for me.

As I am working in **ASP.Net 1.1**, so can not handle this .net level.

So I went ahead a tried many solution i.e **using javascript library, jquery library** to do this.

Some tool are converting, but appending **<0>, <1> <2>** and so on..Which while doing LoadXml is throwing format error.

I need a simple function or a good library which can convert a JSON object to XML.

Please suggest if there are any.

I have tried these to name a few :

[This gave me the xml having <0>, <1> ,<2> sort of tags.](http://code.google.com/p/x2js/)

[This Did not work at all.](http://ruchirawageesha.blogspot.in/2011/06/xml-to-json-and-json-to-xml-conversion.html)

**EDIT**

I have deleted the middle JSON and XML data as it was huge :

JSON

```
"{\"CrashTestResult\":[[\"Crash Test Note\",\"Results based on a 35 MPH frontal crash and 38.5 MPH side crash.  Results are reported in a range of one to five stars, with five stars indicating the best crash protection for vehicles within \\"TIRES, P265/70R17 ALL-SEASON, BLACKWALL\",\"$0.00\"],[\"TIRES\",\"TIRES, P265/70R17 ON-/OFF-ROAD, WHITE OUTLINED-LETTER\",\"$125.00\"],[\"TIRES\",\"TIRES, P265/70R17 ON-/OFF-ROAD, BLACKWALL\",\"$150.00\"],[\"TIRES\",\"TIRES, P265/70R17 ALL-SEASON, WHITE OUTLINED-LETTER\",\"$125.00\"],[\"TIRES\",\"TIRES, P275/55R20 ALL-SEASON, BLACKWALL\",\"$0.00\"],[\"Drivetrain Years\",\"5\"],[\"Roadside Assistance Miles/km\",\"100,000\"],[\"Roadside Assistance Years\",\"5\"]],\"Wheel\":[\"WHEELS, 4 - 17\\\" X 7.5\\\" (43.2 CM X 19.1 CM) ALUMINUM, 5-SPOKE\",\"WHEELS, 4 - 17\\\" X 7.5\\\" (43.2 CM X 19.1 CM) ALUMINUM, 5-SPOKE\",\"WHEELS, 4 - 20\\\" X 8.5\\\" (50.8 CM X 21.6 CM) PAINTED ALUMINUM\"]}"
```

Want XML like

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<VINDescription xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n  <CrashTestResult xmlns=\"http://autoexact.com/VINDecoder/\">\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Crash Test Note</string>\r\n      <string>Results based on a 35 MPH frontal crash and 38.5 MPH side crash.  Results are reported in a range of one to five stars, with five stars indicating the best crash protection for vehicles within the same weight class.  This test used driver and passenger belts and airbags.</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Frontal Driver</string>\r\n      <string>* * * *</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Frontal Passenger</string>\r\n      <string>* * * *</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n<string>$2,755.00</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>CPOS PKG</string>\r\n      <string>28F CUSTOMER PREmas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Basic Miles/km</string>\r\n      <string>36,000</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Basic Years</string>\r\n      <string>3</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Corrosion Miles/km</string>\r\n      <string>100,000</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Corrosion Years</string>\r\n      <string>5</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Drivetrain Miles/km</string>\r\n      <string>36,000</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Drivetrain Note</string>\r\n      <string>Unlimited Years/Unlimited Miles for vehicles sold after 07/26/2007</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n    <ArrayOfstring xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays\">\r\n      <string>Drivetrain Years</string>\r\n      <string>3</string>\r\n    </ArrayOfstring>\r\n  </Warranty>\r\n  <Wheel xmlns=\"http://autoexact.com/VINDecoder/\" />\r\n</VINDescription>"
```

Comment: Is your XML element name "0"? Because XML elements cannot start with numbers (so obviously they can't be a number). That's why you're getting format errors, and no self-respecting XML library should allow it.

Comment: No...after converting the json to xml...the library is making such <0> <1> type of tags...That is why I am looking for a better library or function.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your source JSON and what you want the XML to look like?

Comment: @MattBurland..I have a piece of data ..plz suggest me if there is a way..

Answer (score 0):

Hi try something like this. This works great for my applications, but haven't used it outside them so hope it helps.

```
public string ParseJsonToXml(string sJsonObject)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sXMLJson));
        string sXMLDeSerialized = (string)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        ms.Close();
        return sXMLDeSerialized;
    }
```

I parse it to string in order so that i can convert the xml into a dataset and vice versa.

```
public DataSet ParseXmlToDataSet(string sXml)
    {      
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sXml);
        ds.ReadXml(sr);
        return ds;
    }
```

to get the XML of the dataset use

```
//ds is typeof(DataSet)
ds.GetXml();
```

Note:
This is how my data processed looks like

```
<DATA>
<TLOGIN>
    <USER>thabo.pali@za.pwc.com</USER>
    <PASSWORD>"Monday@01</PASSWORD>
</TLOGIN>
</DATA>
```

Regards George

Comment: @George... This is the simplest way to do it..BUT I am in ASP.NET 1.1 :(

Comment: @Learner then I'm afraid i can't help mate. Hope you find your answer.