# How to re-order a tokenized list in XSLT and read two values from it at a time?

Tags: xslt, geojson, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I have some code (from GeoNetwork) which needs to convert Geography Markup Language (in XML) into GeoJSON. I'm currently trying to add functionality to read a polygon formed from a posList, but I'm having a hard time conceptualizing/drafting out what I would need to do.

The 'input' is basically a string consisting of a bunch of coordinates. So it might look something like this

```
<gml:LinearRing gml:id="p21" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326">
    <gml:posList srsDimension="2">45.67 88.56 55.56 88.56 55.56 89.44 45.67 89.44</gml:posList>
 </gml:LinearRing >
```

(Borrowed from Wikipedia's sample).
I can chunk this up in XSLT using something like

```
<xsl:variable name="temp" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(gml:LinearRing/gml:posList))" '\s'/>
```

which should give me `Temp =`

`('45.67', '88.56', '55.56', '88.56', '55.56', '89.44', '45.67', '89.44')`

Problem 1: GeoJSON wants everything in WGS 84 (EPSG 4326) and in the (long, lat) order - but strict adherence to WGS 84 rules (which I expect gml follows) means the coordinates are in (lat, long) order - so the list needs to be re-ordered. (I think - this is very confusing to me still)

Problem 2: GeoJSON wants coordinate pairs, but I just have a list of coordinates.

My current idea is to do something like this:

```
<geom>
<xsl:text>{"type": "Polygon",</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>"coordinates": [
[</xsl:text>

<xsl:variable name="temp" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(gml:LinearRing/gml:posList))" '\s'/>
<xsl:for-each select="$temp">
  <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', $saved, ', ', ., ']')" separator=","/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:variable name="saved" value="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>]
] 
}</xsl:text>
</geom>
```

but I'm unsure whether XSL will let me continuously write a variable like this, and whether there might be a better/more-efficient solution to the problem. (I have a lot of experience in MATLAB, where I would solve this quickly, if not efficiently, using for-loops)

Ideally I would get output similar to

```
<geom>
{"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
  [
  [88.56, 45.67],
  [88.56, 55.56],
  [89.44, 55.56],
  [89.44, 45.67]
  ]
]
}
</geom>
```

(There's a whole other can-of-worms to be had with figuring out whether the polygon is right or left handed, I think)

Comment: What version of XSLT can you use? 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0? If you can use version 3.0, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48947872/1305969) may solve your problem.

Comment: Interesting question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet with any input (not used)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:my="dummy"
                exclude-result-prefixes="my">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence select="
            my:reverseByTuple(
                  ('45.67', '88.56', '55.56', '88.56', '55.56', '89.44', '45.67', '89.44')
            )"/>
   </xsl:template> 
   <xsl:function name="my:reverseByTuple">
        <xsl:param name="items"/>
        <xsl:sequence 
            select="if (empty($items))
                    then ()
                    else ($items[2], $items[1], my:reverseByTuple($items[position()>2]))"
                    />
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
88.56 45.67 88.56 55.56 89.44 55.56 89.44 45.67
```

I really don't understand why you are serializating the JSON instead of ussing a well documented library like the functions in XSLT 3.0... But just for fun, this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:my="dummy"
                exclude-result-prefixes="my">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of 
        select="
          my:encloseWithBracket(
            my:reverseByTupleEncloseWithBracket(
              ('45.67', '88.56', '55.56', '88.56', '55.56', '89.44', '45.67', '89.44')
            )
          )"/>
   </xsl:template> 
   <xsl:function name="my:reverseByTupleEncloseWithBracket">
        <xsl:param name="items"/>
        <xsl:sequence 
            select="if (empty($items))
                    then ()
                    else (my:encloseWithBracket(($items[2],$items[1])),
                          my:reverseByTupleEncloseWithBracket($items[position()>2]) )"
                    />
    </xsl:function>
   <xsl:function name="my:encloseWithBracket">
        <xsl:param name="items"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',string-join($items,','),']')"/>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
[[88.56,45.67],[88.56,55.56],[89.44,55.56],[89.44,45.67]]
```

Comment: "I really don't understand why you are serializating the JSON instead of ussing a well documented library like the functions in XSLT 3.0" Well, for the most part it's because I am not actually aware of these functions! I've basically picked up everything I know about xslt from reading GeoNetwork code at this point...

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but this ended up being the answer I used, with some modifications: the main reasoning being that it supported an arbitrary number of points along with using XSLT 2.0 (due to the limitations of GeoNetwork, I can't use XSLT 3.0). I ended up being wrong about needing to reverse the points, so I was able to simplify this somewhat, and I had to do some string-join shenanigans because I couldn't call a template in the part of the code I was working in. Hopefully this helps if someone else encounters a similar problem.

Comment: I’m glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 support can represent JSON as maps/arrays and serialize them as JSON so you could compute an XPath map from your sequence of coordinates:

```
serialize(
    map { 
      'type' : 'polygon', 
      'coordinates' : array { 
          let $seq := tokenize(gml:LinearRing/gml:posList, '\s+') 
          return $seq[position() mod 2 = 0]![., let $p := position() return $seq[($p - 1) * 2 + 1]] 
         }
    },
    map { 'method' : 'json', 'indent' : true() }
)
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfu/1

To get JSON numbers in the arrays use `let $seq := tokenize(., '\s+')!number()` instead of `let $seq := tokenize(gml:LinearRing/gml:posList, '\s+')`.

If you have access to an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon PE or EE or Altova supporting higher-order functions you could reduce that to

```
        serialize(
          map {
            'type': 'polygon',
            'coordinates': array {
                let $seq := tokenize(gml:LinearRing/gml:posList, '\s+'),
                    $odd := $seq[position() mod 2 = 1],
                    $even := $seq[position() mod 2 = 0]
                return
                    for-each-pair($odd, $even, function ($c1, $c2) {
                        [$c2, $c1]
                    })
            }
          }, 
          map {
            'method': 'json',
            'indent': true()
          }
        )
```

Comment: Good answer. About High Order Functions: a good recomendation is to test Zorba, an Open Source XQuery processor [supporting HOF](http://www.zorba.io/blog/68774681365/zorba-29--io). There is also a [live demo](http://try.zorba.io/)

Comment: @Alejandro, BaseX is also an open-source XQuery processor and it supports XQuery 3.1 with HOF and maps and arrays while Zorba has opted for JSONiq instead on top of XQuery 3.0. eXist-db is another XQuery 3 processor with maps and array support and has an online demo at http://demo.exist-db.org/exist/apps/eXide/index.html where above code runs fine.

Comment: This is a really clever answer but I think (not 100% sure yet) that our processor only supports XSLT 2.0. I'll try to confirm what version we support and if possible edit the question, but thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XSLT-2.0 stylesheet to get your desired outcome. It makes use of the `xsl:analyze-string` function to separate the values in 2-tuples. The template includes error handling and removes the target namespace `gml` from the output with `exclude-result-prefixes="gml"`. You may have to adjust the XML paths of the template and the `xsl:analyze-string` expression. But I guess that you can handle this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326" exclude-result-prefixes="gml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
<geom><xsl:text>
{"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
  [
</xsl:text>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="gml:LinearRing/gml:posList" 
        regex="\s*(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\s+(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\s*"> 
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('    [',regex-group(3),'.', regex-group(4),', ',regex-group(1),'.', regex-group(2),']&#xa;')"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:message terminate="yes">=============================&#xA;=== ERROR: Invalid input! ===&#xA;=============================</xsl:message>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
<xsl:text>  ]
]
}
</xsl:text>
</geom>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<geom>
{"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
  [
    [88.56, 45.67]
    [88.56, 55.56]
    [89.44, 55.56]
    [89.44, 45.67]
  ]
]
}
</geom>%
```

Comment: Looking at this answer, it seems that this assumes the posList has exactly 4 entries. Unfortunately posList is merely a minimum of 4 entries - I chose a 4-entry posList just for simplicity.